# terminal closed -- exit mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write

Tags: mysql

mysqldump --single-transaction  -u xx -h xxxx  -P3306 -p'lq2' test user_total_label --where="true" |  mysql -u root -p'#1xxGw.' test

#desc
logs shows "terminal closed -- exit  mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write"
it not always have error,it happen sometimes

Answer (score 0):

errno 32 means a broken pipe.

If you install the perror utility, it will show you the error message -
[~]: perror 32
OS error code  32:  Broken pipe

It would be best to mysqldump the database first to a file and then pipe the file into the destination host.  With large databases, a broken pipe may occur.

Step 1:
mysqldump --single-transaction -u xx -h xxxx -P3306 -p'lq2' test user_total_label --where="true" -r results.sql
Step 2:
mysql -u root -p'#1xxGw.' test < results.sql